# jQuery/AJAX Multiple File Upload in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, upload

I am trying to get a box on my site that allows for multiple files to be dragged and uploaded to my server. So far, it seems like my AJAX is working. My upload function is as below:

```
  function AjaxFileUpload(files, progressBar, container){

    //Creates a formdata object for the upload, appends a CSRF token, the file itself and its respective name
    var formData = new FormData;
    formData.append('_token', CSRF_TOKEN);
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
      formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: 'upload',
      type: 'post',
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR)); console.log('AJAX Error: ' + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);},
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  }
```

The way my files are handled on the serverside is in my **UploadController@upload**. (And yes I have a POST route in my **web.php** for this.

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
  public function upload(Request $request){
    $arr = [];
    foreach($request->all() as $file){
      if(is_file($file)){
        $string = str_random(16);
        $size = filesize($file);
        $ext = $file->guessExtension();
        $file_name = $string . '.' .  $ext;
        $filepath = 'storage/uploads/' . Auth::user()->email . '/' . $file_name;
        $file->storeAs(('uploads/' . Auth::user()->email), $file_name);
        array_push($arr, [
          'name' => $file_name,
          'path' => $filepath,
          'mime' => $ext,
          'size' => $size
        ]);
      }

    }
    return $arr;
  }
}
```

When I drag a file into my sample box on my browser, the console successfully returns an array with the name of the file and its supposed location, like so:

[image]

However when I check my directories (both public/storage/uploads and storage/uploads), I do not see any files. Is there a setting I have to enable? I checked my config/filesystems.php file and it looks like this:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

EDIT: The html composing my upload box. There is no associated 'form' where I can specify enctype

```
  <div data-regard="" data-id="" class="upload-container">
    <div class="file-drag">
      Drag onto me
    </div>
    <progress class="uk-progress" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, it isn't a form but rather just a div on my site. I will show the HTML in an edit. How do I associated these files with a form in that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
  public function upload(Request $request){
    $arr = [];
    foreach($request->all() as $file){
      if(is_file($file)){
        $string = str_random(16);
        $size = filesize($file);
        $ext = $file->guessExtension();
        $file_name = $string . '.' .  $ext;
        $filepath = 'storage/uploads/' . Auth::user()->email . '/' . $file_name;
        $file->storeAs(('uploads/' . Auth::user()->email), $file_name);
        array_push($arr, [
          'name' => $file_name,
          'path' => $filepath,
          'mime' => $ext,
          'size' => $size
        ]);
      }

    }
    return $arr;
  }
}
```

> Just replace it $file->storeAs(('uploads/' . Auth::user()->email), $file_name); to $file->storeAs('storage/uploads/' . Auth::user()->email, 'public');